# What is the degree of freedom of semiparametric method for mixture distribution

Tags: distributions, mixture-distribution, degrees-of-freedom, semiparametric

In the semi-parametric method for density analysis, I want to compare one component semi-parametric mixture distribution and two components mixture distribution. Semi-parametric here means the shape of the distribution is total flexible but symmetric, an even PDF. As there is no variables in the semi- method, the PDF is quite flexible, what is the degree of freedom in this question?

Comment: Could you explain what "degree of freedom" might mean here?  What are you hoping to use it for?

Comment: @whuber I want to do likelihood ratio test to compare two component semi mixture model and one component semi model. In likelihood ratio test, I need to know the difference of degree of freedom between these two model.